# Error while storing a list of custom object in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I have a custom class of the following type

```
[Table]
class MyApp
{
    public MyApp()
        : base()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string appCode { get; set; }

    [Column(UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string procCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class which contains a list of MyApp objects which is as below:

```
[Table]
class ApplicationUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() 
        :base()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string userId { get; set; }

    [Column(UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public List<MyApp> applicationList { get; set; }
}
```

While calling the CreateDatabase() method in my DataContext class i get the following error:

```
Unable to determine SQL type for 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XCell.Framework.data.MyApp]'
```

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Just to check - as I understand the `ApplicationUser` should relate to `MyApp` as one-to-many, right ?

Comment: @danyloid Yes. One application user can have multiple apps.

Comment: Is it possible that one application is assigned to several users ?

Comment: Yes this is possible. But on a mobile it is assumed that there is only one user.

Answer (score 1):

As I see the problem is that the `applicationList` is marked with the `Column` attribute, though it represents a relation.

Basically you will have to correctly map the relation between those entities using `EntityRef<T>` and `EntitySet<T>` classes and the `Association` attribute.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37784/One-Many-and-One-One-relationship-using-LINQ-to-SQ) may be helpful.

The example with the corrected mapping (for one-to-many relation) below:

Adjusted `ApplicationUser` class

```
[Table]
public class ApplicationUser
{
    private EntitySet<MyApp> _userApplications = new EntitySet<MyApp>();

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage = "_userApplications", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey = "ApplicationUserId")]
    public EntitySet<MyApp> ApplicationList
    {
        get { return _userApplications; }
        set { _userApplications = value; }
    }
}
```

And the adjusted `MyApp` class

```
[Table]
public class MyApp
{
    private EntityRef<ApplicationUser> _applicationUserRef;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string AppCode { get; set; }

    [Column(UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string ProcCode { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [Association(Name = "FK_MyApp_ApplicationUser", Storage = "_applicationUserRef", ThisKey = "ApplicationUserId", OtherKey = "UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUserReference
    {
        get { return _applicationUserRef.Entity; }
        set { _applicationUserRef.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the `ApplicationUserId` property `Column` attribute